# Get %appdata% of remote computer

Tags: c#, appdata

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to expand environment variables remotely with .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031111/how-to-expand-environment-variables-remotely-with-net)

I need to get the %appdata% of a remote computer in C#. I know i can do it locally with Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), but how can i get that info on a remote computer?
i can't seem to find that specific attribute in the WMI.

Comment: Have a look at

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031111/how-to-expand-environment-variables-remotely-with-net/5031419#5031419

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979415/access-appdata-on-distant-computer-net-openremotebasekey

Does this post answer your question?

Comment: no because on the first link Win32_OperatingSystem does not have the %appdata% info (tried it before) and the second link depends on OS, and i want generic